# Input 4-digit number using 4*4 keypad and show in serial monitor

Tags: arduino-mega

```
#include <Keypad.h>

int myNum[4];

const byte ROWS = 4; 
const byte COLS = 4; 
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {5, 4, 3, 2}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad 8,7,6,5
byte colPins[COLS] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad 4,3,2,1
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Enter four-digit num -");  // request for input
  for (int i = 0; i < 4;){
    if(keypad.getKey()!= NO_KEY) {
      myNum[i] = keypad.getKey();
      i = i+1;
    }
  }
  Serial.print("Entered number is = ");
  Serial.print(myNum[0]);
  Serial.print(myNum[1]);
  Serial.print(myNum[2]);
  Serial.println(myNum[3]);
  delay(500);
}
```

I want that when I press a 4-digit number on the keypad it should be shown in the serial monitor. This code gives 0000 when I press any key on keypad.

Answer (score 1):

`keypad.getKey()` is non-blocking as you can read [here](https://playground.arduino.cc/Code/Keypad): it will return a value immediately, even if no key is pressed.  You have a `for` loop which will increment `i` each time, and you also increment it yourself. So what's happening is that your code is immediately making four readings, all of which are no-key-pressed so it doesn't store them, and then printing whatever happens to be in the `myNum` buffer.

Instead, you need to wait each time until a key is pressed, and only then move to the next digit. There are of course many ways you could do this.  I hope this is clear:

```
#include <Keypad.h>

int myNum[4];

const byte ROWS = 4; 
const byte COLS = 4; 
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {5, 4, 3, 2}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad 8,7,6,5
byte colPins[COLS] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad 4,3,2,1
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Enter four-digit num -");  // request for input

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
    while((myNum[i] = keypad.getKey())==NO_KEY) {
      delay(1); // Just wait for a key
    } 
    // Wait for the key to be released
    while(keypad.getKey() != NO_KEY) {
      delay(1);
    } 

  }

  Serial.print("Entered number is = ");
  Serial.print(myNum[0]);
  Serial.print(myNum[1]);
  Serial.print(myNum[2]);
  Serial.println(myNum[3]);
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: You are welcome. If the answer helps you, please consider accepting it.

Comment: when i compile it there is a error code "Serial does not name a type" .

Comment: I assumed you had tested your original code, since you described how it didn't work. No?

Comment: @kasun That kind of error usually occurs when you try to execute a statement outside of any function. Did you omit a curly brace around setup() or loop()? Show the exact code that gives you the error!

Comment: thnks friend . thats { is bother  me

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
  while((myNum[i] = keypad.getKey())!=NO_KEY) {
    delay(1); // Just wait for a key
  } 
}  its not working properly. can u send me a full code for that

Comment: Put that in your code where you previously had the for() loop.

Comment: I did it but its not working properly. can u send me a whole code.

Comment: I've included the rest of the code above and fixed a bug (sorry).  I've also added some code to make sure the first key is released before reading the next key. If it still isn't working, please describe exactly how it behaves and how that is wrong. But it would be better if you tried to debug it yourself - that way you'll understand what it happening.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <Keypad.h>

char myNum[4];

const byte ROWS = 4; 
const byte COLS = 4; 
char keys[ROWS][COLS] = {
  {'1','2','3','A'},
  {'4','5','6','B'},
  {'7','8','9','C'},
  {'*','0','#','D'}
};
byte rowPins[ROWS] = {5, 4, 3, 2}; //connect to the row pinouts of the keypad 8,7,6,5
byte colPins[COLS] = {9, 8, 7, 6}; //connect to the column pinouts of the keypad 4,3,2,1
Keypad keypad = Keypad(makeKeymap(keys), rowPins, colPins, ROWS, COLS );

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop() {
  Serial.println("Enter four-digit num -");  // request for input

  for (char i = 0; i < 4; ++i){
    while((myNum[i] = keypad.getKey())==NO_KEY) {
      delay(1); // Just wait for a key
    } 
    // Wait for the key to be released
    while(keypad.getKey() != NO_KEY) {
      delay(1);
    } 

  }

  Serial.print("Entered number is = ");
  Serial.print(myNum[0]);
  Serial.print(myNum[1]);
  Serial.print(myNum[2]);
  Serial.println(myNum[3]);
  delay(500);
}
```